# Subdomains not opening when prefixed with www for site hosted in Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, dns, web-hosting

I have created a mvc multi tenant site and hosted in Azure. So if my website is:
**mysite.com** I dynamically create **1.mysite.com**, **2.mysite.com** depending upon user's sign up information. I have created these
**A records**:

```
  www.mysite.com   1.2.3.4( Assume this is Azure's IP)
  mysite.com       1.2.3.4
  *.mysite.com     1.2.3.4
```

My subdomain websites work well when I open them as 1.mysite.com. But if I try to open **www.1.mysite.com** it shows me the **Azure 404 page not found error**.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Some systems automatically add the www. A records when a domain or subdomain is entered, it may be that it has/does not on Azure.

There may be a way to make it do this automatically that someone more knowledgabel on Azure may post below but a short term fix would be to manually add the A record.

Comment: How do I manually add A record for wildcard subdomains? I want something like:                                                                                    www.*.mysite.com     1.2.3.4